# Detect when user has finished editing a cell in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using `DataGridView1.CellEndEdit` to detect when the user finishes to edit a cell.

In my program i am doing this:

- Filling a Datagridview with a binding source
- Filtering with the bindingsource filter
- order by the first column alphabetically
- edit a cell
- Write edited values in the database

The problem is: When I finish CellEndEdit is fired and the cell does this:

- write new values to Datagridview
- **Refresh row order based on the new value of the cell and update the bindingsource filter**
- Fire CellEndEdit

For me this is a problem because I need to read the content of every cell of the row, in order to update the database and once it gets the new values it is moved to a unknown position OR hidden because it does not meet the filter criteria anymore and thus if I read the row it was before I get the values of a row that has nothing to do with the one I am looking for.

Is there a way to get the values of the entire row containing the cell i just edited from within the CellEndEdit sub?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding a KeyUp event handler and storing each cell of the row in a variable on every keyup event.

Answer (score 1):

The [CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event provides [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) arguments which contains the [RowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.rowindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. i Updated teh question at the same time as you answered. Added the filter part. I am afraid that even havint the row index will not fix that problem.